# Session_OnEnd event on Global.asa, concurrency issue

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, global.asa

In my application,I am using `Session_OnEnd` event on `global.asa` file to log the logged out user details to one of my table. For that I am creating an object of one of my VB component from `Session_OnEnd` event and from there I am inserting into one of my table.

In certain scenarios (Multiple user’s session end happens at a time), we are getting an Unhandled exception while creating above object, since my 1st request is already in processing status.

Anybody of you suggest any good method to overcome this issue?

```
Dim objClean
Set objClean= Server.CreateObject("Clean.clsClean")
Call objClean.Cleanup(Session, Application)
Set objClean= Nothing
```

`Set objClean= Server.CreateObject("Clean.clsClean")` this line is throwing an exception in my case.

Comment: Yeah, don't use a VB Component or rely on Classic ASP built-in in-memory session handling.

Comment: Lankymart,  Can you suggest any way to overcome this one?

Comment: Not apart from what I've already said. It's most likely a concurrency issue, trying to use COM transactionally in Classic ASP is a minefield.

Comment: @user729271 Could you move this code to a logout button or page, instead of relying on Session_OnEnd in global.asa?  As Lankymart indicates, instantiating server objects (even temporarily or indirectly) in Session_OnEnd is typically not ideal.